# Remove empty columns from HTML string

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, regex

I wrote code that removes the empty rows in the tables from the `str` variable.

I need help in removing the empty columns from the tables in the `str`.

Note that tables can have different amounts of cells in each row.
all the columns should be removed from the str

```js
let str =
  `<head></head><body><h1>table 1</h1><table><thead><tr><th><p>a1</p></th><th></th><th><p>a3</p></th><th><p>a4</p></th><th></th></tr><tr><th>b1</th><th></th><th><p>b3</p></th><th colspan="2"><p>b4</p></th></tr><tr><th>c1</th><th></th><th>c3</th><th>c4</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr><tr><td><p>f1</p></td><td></td><td></td><td><p>f4</p></td><td>f5</td></tr></tbody></table><p>lorem table</p><h2>table 2</h2><table><thead><tr><th><p>a1</p></th><th></th><th><p>a3</p></th><th><p>a4</p></th><th></th></tr><tr><th>b1</th><th></th><th><p>b3</p></th><th colspan="2"><p>b4</p></th></tr><tr><th>c1</th><th></th><th>c3</th><th>c4</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr><tr><td><p>f1</p></td><td></td><td></td><td><p>f4</p></td><td>f55</td></tr></tbody></table></body>`
  
const emptyCellRegex = /<(t[dh])>(\s*?)<\/\1>/g;
let tableTags = str.match(/<table.*?<\/table>/gs);
let isEmptyCol = true
let t, r, c = 0
let isEmptyRow = true
let isEmptyCell;

for (t = 0; t < tableTags.length; t++) {
  let tableTag = tableTags[t]
  let trTags = [];

  const matches = tableTag.match(/<tr.*?<\/tr>/gs);
  if (matches) {
    trTags.push(...matches);
  }

  // delete rows
  for (r = 0; r < trTags.length; r++) {
    let trTag = trTags[r];
    let tdTags = []; // include th and td tags

    const matches = trTag.match(/<(td|th).*?<\/(td|th)>/gs);

    if (matches) {
      tdTags.push(...matches);
    }

    for (c = 0; c < tdTags.length; c++) {
      let tdTag = tdTags[c];
      emptyCellRegex.lastIndex = 0; // reset the search position

      isEmptyCell = emptyCellRegex.exec(tdTag) !== null
      if (!isEmptyCell) {
        isEmptyRow = false;
      }

    }
    if (isEmptyRow) str = str.replace(trTag, '');
    isEmptyRow = true
  }
}
/// -end- delete rows


// Remove columns...

console.log("str: ", str)
```

Comment: Is it intentional that the tables have multiple rows fo headers? Why are there empty `<th>` tags to begin with? What is considered an empty column? Do we count the headers?

Comment: Don't use regex to process HTML. Use [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) instead.

Answer (score 0):

in the section of your code where you loop through the `trTags` and check for empty cells with `emptyCellRegex`, you can create another regex for  tags and loop through them as well saving the index of the empty , and the number of times that index appears in subsequent  rows.

After looping through them, check if the counters is equal to trTags.length, this would indicate the column you are trying to remove.

Now you can go through your `trTags` to remove the correct column